# Treemap and byte[]

Tags: java, collections

I have class whose member is `byte[]` I need to put object of the class in `TreeMap` with `key` as object of this class. Following is I have written, but `put` and `get` is not working as per expectation.

```
import java.io.IOException;
import java.nio.ByteBuffer;
import java.util.Arrays;    

public class XTObject Comparable<XTObject>{
    public byte[] data; 
    public XTObject(){

    }
    public XTObject(final byte[] in) {
        this.data = in;
    }   


    @Override
  public boolean equals(final Object obj) {
        if (this == obj)
      return true;
   if (obj == null)
      return false;
   if (getClass() != obj.getClass())
      return false;
   XTObject other = (XTObject) obj;
   if (!Arrays.equals(data, other.data))
      return false;
   return true;
    }
    @Override
  public int hashCode() {
        return Arrays.hashCode(data);       
    }
    @Override
    public int compareTo(XTObject o) {
        ByteBuffer left = ByteBuffer.wrap(this.data);
        ByteBuffer right = ByteBuffer.wrap(o.data);
        return left.compareTo(right);

    }

}
```

Put is working fine I guess, but `get` is giving null pointer exception. I am new to java.

Comment: Where is the code to put and get?

Comment: maybe it's cause you don't initialize field `data` if you use parameter-less constructor, so data == null

Comment: How are you using the treemap?

Comment: Take out default constructor and try, so you will be forced to pass in byte array.

Answer (score 2):

You should make sure that `data` member is always initialized during construction or that you handle potential null values.
In cases were the data member is not initialized you are exposed to `NullPointerExecption` in the `equals`, `hashCode` and `compareTo` methods.
The [TreeMap](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/TreeMap.html) is a [SortedMap](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/SortedMap.html) and will use the compareTo method for sorting the map elements.